# index out of bounds with UICollectionViews with different amount of items embedded in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a UITableView (vertically scrollable), where each row (Custom TableViewCell) contains a UICollectionView with some CollectionView cells (horizontally scrollable)

However, the collection views have different amount of collection view cells: some have just two or three, others have more than ten.

The problem is: when I am on a row with a collection view that has very many cells and horizontally scroll all the way over to the last cell, and THEN scroll down vertically to a collection view that has only a few collection view cells, I get `index out of bounds`, because the row is reused and scrolled to further to the right than there are collection view items.

Do you have an idea how I can prevent this? Maybe by preparing for reuse?

Comment: As you note, cells are reused... so, each time you `dequeue a Reusable Cell` you need to make sure it is "cleaned up". So, since you are calling `dequeueReusableCell` in `cellForRowAt`, that is where you want to reset / reinitialize the elements in your cell.

Comment: hmm that's what I thought, but do you have an idea how exactly to clean the cells up and prepare them for being reused? It would be necessary to reset horizontal scrolling in a collection view that is a tableviewcell, and to properly calculate the number of collection view cells. I think I'm a little bit stuck right now

Comment: There are various approaches, and it would depend on exactly how your data is structured. It's been a while, but I know I played around with the project from this article - might be a good thing for you to read through: https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 1.reload collection in UITableview cell row at indexpath
 2.before reload collectionView remove all array belong to collection view
```

Comment: thanks,  with `cell.collectionView.reloadData()` it seems to work :)